# cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: extra/7/x86_64

Tags: centos, yum

I've set up a fresh VM(CeotOS7) in vmware. However, I failed to update yum.

It returns cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: extra/7/x86_64.

I've tried all the solutions on the Internet and still can't fix it.

I can ping google.com, curl http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=i386&repo=os returns <'http><'head><'title>Firewall Authentication <'/title>

I've also tried to modify CentOS-Base.repo hundreds of times.

Firewall and SELinux both disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You might have already solved problem. It might help other.
I run following commands

```sh
[root@myserver]# ONBOOT=no
[root@myserver]# dhclient
[root@myserver]# yum update
```